# Partial ajax submit with jsf 1.2 with richfaces

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

i have this model

```
guy
    name
    age
    city
    country
    list<girlfriends>
```

and i have this jsf 1.2 + richfaces 3.3.3 form

```
form
    panelgroup#first-part
        input#name
        input#age
        input#city
        input#country
    a4j:region
        input#girlfriends
        submit#addgirlfriends
    panelgroup
        datatable#girlfriends
    a4j:commandButton#save
```

So, i have this `a4j:commandButton#save` for save all.
But when I click on my button save, all form is submited, but i want submit only `panelgroup#first-part`. How can i do this?

edit: using a real scenario

## Cadastro de Contato

```
    <rich:messages id="messages" />

    <a4j:region>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="form-contato">
            <label>Nome</label>
            <h:inputText value="#{cadastrocontato.contato.nome}" id="nome" />

            <label>Email</label>
            <h:inputText value="#{cadastrocontato.contato.email}" id="email"
                required="true" requiredMessage="O email deve ser digitado" />

            <label>Número</label>
            <h:inputText value="#{cadastrocontato.contato.numero}" />
        </h:panelGrid>

        <a4j:commandButton value="Cadastrar"
            actionListener="#{cadastrocontato.add}" process="nome"
            reRender="form-contato, datatable-contatos, messages">
        </a4j:commandButton>
    </a4j:region>
```

When i set the `nome` field.. the field `email` that is required, throws a required message. But I processed only the `nome` field, how can i do this work?

Answer (score 0):

You are using RF 3.3.3?

**process**-attribute should do the trick: http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/commandButton.jsf?tab=info&cid=321214

Comment: the process attribute not work, i will update de main question with a real scenario